# why does ldap have all these funny two letter codes

Tags: ldap

couldn't they make it simple, all you need is just uid and passwd, but they have all this stuff like cn and dn and base dn, it's too complicated

: dc=,dc= 
objectclass: dcObject 
objectclass: organization 
o:  
dc:

dn: cn=Manager,dc=,dc= 
objectclass: organizationalRole 
cn: Manager

Comment: How exactly do you expect people to answer this question? "Because", or "to make new users ask why", or "they liked two letter abbreviations"? Voting to close as "not a real question".

Comment: Because they wanted to make it more flexible than what you are describing, would be a reasonable guess.

Comment: There's no real answer to this.  Vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the 2-letter-codes: To keep the format terse. There is "no reason" (except to not annoy the system admins more than necessary ;-) why full names couldn't have been forced.

Now as to the complexity (and it is complex!) and why all these different parts exist? Well, [that's just LDAP](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch3/):

> > The complexity and power of LDAP comes from the fact that there are bucket loads of attributes and bucket loads of objectclasses liberally scattered round in apparently randomly (and invariably unhelpfully) named schemas.

That is, LDAP is *not* just a user/password scheme.

Happy coding.